# Remove sensitive Headers from Azure PaaS hosted Websites

Tags: security, azure, azure-web-app-service, iis-8

If you follow this article [Azure Blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/removing-standard-server-headers-on-windows-azure-web-sites/), you can remove the Server, X-Powered-By and MVC version which is great.

You can also achieve similar with a custom IIS module with the following method:

```
private void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpContext.Current?.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
   HttpContext.Current?.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
   HttpContext.Current?.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
   HttpContext.Current?.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
}
```

However, if you send the following query string:

https://**yourAppService**.azurewebsites.net/**test.txt:**

You manage to avoid all the steps you've taken to avoid sending the headers you are trying to keep away from potential hackers.

Sample Request:

[image: Sample Request]

Sample Response:
[image]

Is there a way to completely remove these headers from **ALL** responses, and not just requests the app manages to handle gracefully? I have managed to remove the headers from 99% of responses, but not all!

### UPDATE:

I have also found if you use PostMan to send a GET request to

https://yourSite.azurewebsites.net/**400errortest%00**

you get

[image]

### UPDATE:

The request to /test.txt: was reported fixed by MS on the 26th June 2017. I can confirm it is fixed for this scenario.

Requests to https://yourSite.azurewebsites.net/**400errortest%00** via PostMan still return a Server Header which is not great.

Comment: We could give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps) to azure team that if  we use the url end with `:` to visit the azure website  that we will get 500 error, the default action should be 404 error.

Comment: I added a suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/18384928-remove-sensitive-information-from-headers  please vote for it if you would like to get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If we use the url end with `:` to visit the azure website that we will get 500 error, the default action should be 404 error. Azure team opened an internal [bug](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/16817698-return-40x-for-http-azurewebsites-net) and plan to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I cant really mark this as the answer because its not possible to actually fix the problem yet as it requires action from the PaaS team. When/if the problem can be fixed, I may provide details of any config/code changes a dev has to make to fix this issue and accept my own answer at that point.